# Latexmk: Pass style file to makeindex as an option

Tags: latexmk, makeindex

We need to pass the `-s <our_topelvelsource_directory>/tex/index_style.ist` option to makeindex and currently we do that by reading an environment variable that we set prior to executing `latexmk`

```
$makeindex = "makeindex -s $ENV{CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/tex/index_style.ist -g %O -o %D %S";
```

Command line for latexmk will include `-r ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/latexmk.rc`. Is there another/better option to specify a custom style to `makeindex`?

If we stay at overriding the `makeindex` command-line, then is there a better way to get the path of the `RC` file? We tried using the Perl `__FILE__` variable, but it contains the value `eval(11)` - my guess is that `latexmk` opens a pipe at fds 11 and lets perl read from it. So that didn't work.

Comment: One other possibility is to set makeindex from the command line used to run latexmk, e.g., `latexmk -e '$makeindex = qq(makeindex -s <name of ist file> %O %S);'`.

Comment: At present the only way of accessing the name of the rc file is via an internal undocumented variable of latexmk.  The problem is that to get the needed functionality, latexmk can't use Perl's do function.  Instead it reads in the rc file and then executes the code it has read in.